# Blurry effect using canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

**Intro**

I am creating a page which contains "rows" of information according to the following:

- Every row contains a single canvas
- All the rows must have the same width: the width of the widest canvas
- If the widest canvas has a width less than the viewport, the width of the viewport is used.

The solution is easy an simple: Using a table (with single columns) and the style `min-width: 100%;`. That is not the problem.

**Problem**

Everything that is drawn in the canvases has a blurry effect.

It (apparently) happens in (recent versions of) Chrome only.

**Reproducibility**

In order to reproduce the problem, I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaurenceUgalde/goyrdacj/).

In the example I have created two rows with different background color each, the first canvas renders text, the second one renders graphic content. For the graphic content I am using the following image:

[image: 100 doors]

Please notice that the image contains only two colors: pure red and pure green. Its size is 100x100. In the second canvas the image is shown 10 times, one beside the other, so the canvas width is 1000x100.

The computer I am testing in is a Linux, with Chrome 87.0.4280.66 (2020-11-17), the latest stable version at the moment of writing this question.

I have tested it in other computers and browsers, with the following results:

- Same Linux computer, (old) Chrome: OK
- Same Linux computer, Mozilla: OK
- Another Linux computer, (recent) Chrome: PROBLEM
- Another Linux computer, Mozilla: OK
- MacBook, (recent) Chrome: PROBLEM
- MacBook, Mozilla: OK
- MacBook, Safari. OK
- Android tablet, (old) Chrome: OK

If you see all OK and you are wondering how the problem looks, Here is a screenshot. (You may need to click in order to see it at 100%, in adjusted size is hard to see the problem):

[image]

Notice that:

- The image appears blurry, mixing the red an green colors (resulting in a maroon-like one). It is specially notorious around the 5th. image.
- The problem also affects the text. If you see carefully, text above the 5th. square is slightly more diffuse that at the beginning.

The effects is similar to the one achieved if you draw in an image (or in an off-screen canvas), and then draw its content in the canvas using a different scale factor (i.e. drawing an 100x100 image in a 99x99 space), because the effect resembles the typical result of resampling.

**What I have tried, with no success**

1. `context.resetTransform()` before drawing.
2. `context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false`. Even if it worked, it solved the problem for the image, but not for the text.
3. `context.drawImage()` with `dWidth` and `dHeight` parameters, in order to force drawing in a 100x100 target.
4. `#canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }`
5. Chrome -> Settings -> Appareance -> Use hardware acceleration when available -> (disabling)
6. Using another methods for layout. I have tried using DIVs instead of a table.
7. According to [<canvas>: The Graphics Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas):

> Sizing the canvas using CSS versus HTML
>
> The displayed size of the canvas can be changed using CSS, but if you do this the image is scaled during rendering to fit the styled size, which can make the final graphics rendering end up being distorted.
>
> It is better to specify your canvas dimensions by setting the width and height attributes directly on the  elements, either directly in the HTML or by using JavaScript.

All the the canvas stuff is done by Javascript, no CSS, no HTML.

---

Have you experimented this effect somehow before ? Did you solve it ? How ?

Any idea for solution ?

If you experiment he problem, and you have a browser different than Chrome, please comment, in order to exclude the problem as specific of Chrome.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the fact that (0,0) indexes the top-left of the first pixel. A vertical, 1 pixel wide line drawn from here will give full intensity only to the first 1/2 of the pixel. When drawing 1 pixel wide lines, you get much cleaner results if considering (0.5,0.5) to be the center of the pixel. You were actually _almost_ there. In the fiddle, uncomment `context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` and add 0.5 to the X and Y coordinates. Et voila - unmodified copies of the image. :)

Comment: Thanks @enhzflep for your comment. Unfortunately it makes all the 10 images look equal, but these copies are definitively distinct from the original image. Regards

Comment: What does `console.log( devicePixelRatio )` outputs? Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLq8ghbw/) render any better:  Weird you have it ok with other browsers though... Could your browser have some zoom applied?

Comment: Hi @Kaiido. `devicePixelRatio`  reports a weird value of 1.001312255859375. I have verified that no zoom is used. Your fiddle looks perfect!!!, I did not know about the existence of `devicePixelRatio`. I will immediately try it in my page. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, your solution works like a charm. I suggest you write it down as an answer so that I can rate it as the correct one. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires (as noted by @Kaiido), the use of [`Window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio):

> The devicePixelRatio of Window interface returns the ratio of the resolution in physical pixels to the resolution in CSS pixels for the current display device. This value could also be interpreted as the ratio of pixel sizes: the size of one CSS pixel to the size of one physical pixel. In simpler terms, this tells the browser how many of the screen's actual pixels should be used to draw a single CSS pixel.

The code that solves the problem is:

```
if (devicePixelRatio != 1.0) {
    context.canvas.style.width = (context.canvas.width / devicePixelRatio) + "px";
    context.canvas.style.height = (context.canvas.height / devicePixelRatio) + "px";
}
```

This also works in browsers other than Chrome, They (in my own case) return the value 1 for `Window.devicePixelRatio`, leaving the previous functionality intact.